# Exact differential equation Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to solve exact differential equation problem but I couldn't get right answer.Please someone help me with this problem.

$xdy-ydx=\sqrt{x^2-y^2} dx$

Thanks,

Comment: **Hint:** Try letting $y = vx \implies y' = v + v' x$. Divide your equation by $dx$, substitute and solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
xdy-ydx&=\sqrt{x^2-y^2}\ dx\\
\implies\dfrac{xdy-ydx}{x^2}&=\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}{x}\ \dfrac{dx}{x}\\
\implies d\left(\dfrac yx\right)&=\sqrt{1-\dfrac{y^2}{x^2}}\ \dfrac{dx}{x}\\
\implies\int\dfrac{d\left(\dfrac yx\right)}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{y^2}{x^2}}}&=\int\dfrac{dx}{x}+c\qquad [c=\text{integration const.}]\\
\implies\sin^{-1}\left(\dfrac yx\right)&=\ln x+c
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Let $y = vx$ , so that $y' = v + v' x$ and that $dy = (v + v' x) dx$. Then the differential equation
$$x dy - y dx = \sqrt{x^2 - y^2} dx$$ 
becomes 
$$ 
x(v + v' x)dx - (vx)dx = \sqrt{x^2 - v^2 x^2} dx.
$$
Dividing by $dx$, grouping terms, replacing $v'$ with $\frac{dv}{dx}$, and a few further simplifications yields
$$\frac{dv}{dx} x^2 = \sqrt{(1 - v^2)} x.$$
It should be clear that this is now a separable ODE, and you can proceed from here.